Using a for loop when defining a function, but "$i++" was "Unreachable code"
I plan to define a function myimplode() to achieve the same function as implode()
function myimplode($arr, $sep) {
    $str = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($arr); $i++) {
        $str .= $arr[$i];
        if ($i < count($arr) - 1){
            $str .= $sep; // $str = $str . $step
        }
        return $str;
    }
}

however, $i++ didn't run when performing the for loop.
The reason for the error is simply Unreachable code detected.
I don't know why the $i++ was 'unreachable code'.
If I write a separate for loop, this error will not occur, like,
for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {}


Move the return to outside the for loop
